# Getting intermittent "unable to open database file" error after a few transactions in sqlite db in swift

Tags: swift, sqlite

I am using sqlite to save my data in swiftui based app. When I install my app, I am able to connect to sqlite db and do a few insert and read transactions. But after some transactions (around 8-12) I start getting error "unable to open database file".

Here is my how I am connecting to db

```
class DBHelper
{
    init()
    {
        db = openDatabase()
        createTable()
    }
    
    let dbPath: String = "myDb.sqlite"
    var db:OpaquePointer?
    
    func openDatabase() -> OpaquePointer?
    {
        let fileURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
                    .appendingPathComponent(dbPath)
        var db: OpaquePointer? = nil
        print("opened database")
        
        //=================================================================
        if sqlite3_open(fileURL.path, &db) != SQLITE_OK
        {
            let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db))
            print("error opening database = \(errmsg)")
            sqlite3_close(db)
            db = nil
            return nil
        }
        else
        {
            //print("db connection opened at = \(documentUrlPath)")
            return db
        }
    }
    
    func createTable() {
        let createNoteTableString = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS note (id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,datetime INTEGER,title TEXT, description BLOB,type TEXT,theme TEXT, font TEXT, folderId TEXT, isBookmarked INTEGER);"
        var createNoteTableStatement: OpaquePointer? = nil
        if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, createNoteTableString, -1, &createNoteTableStatement, nil) == SQLITE_OK
        {
            if sqlite3_step(createNoteTableStatement) == SQLITE_DONE
            {
                //print("note table created.")
            } else {
                //print(" note table could not be created.")
            }
        } else {
            //print("CREATE note TABLE statement could not be prepared.")
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(createNoteTableStatement)
    } 

    func insert(id:String, datetime:Int64, title:String, description:NSAttributedString, type:String, theme:String, font:String, folderId:String, isBookmarked:Bool)
    {
        let SQLITE_TRANSIENT = unsafeBitCast(-1, to: sqlite3_destructor_type.self)
        //let data: NSData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: description) as NSData
        var isBookmarkedInt = isBookmarked ? 1 : 0;
        let notes = readNotes()
        for p in notes
        {
            if p.id == id
            {
                return
            }
        }
        //insertContent(id: UUID().uuidString, content: description, parentId: id)
        
        let insertStatementString = "INSERT INTO note (id, datetime, title, description, type, theme, font, folderId, isBookmarked) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);"
        var insertStatement: OpaquePointer? = nil
        if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, insertStatementString, -1, &insertStatement, nil) == SQLITE_OK {
            sqlite3_bind_text(insertStatement, 1, (id as NSString).utf8String, -1, nil)
            sqlite3_bind_int64(insertStatement, 2, Int64(datetime))
            sqlite3_bind_text(insertStatement, 3, (title as NSString).utf8String, -1, nil)
            sqlite3_bind_text(insertStatement, 4, (description.string as NSString).utf8String, -1, nil)
            //sqlite3_bind_blob (insertStatement, 4, data.bytes, Int32(data.length), SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(insertStatement, 5, (type as NSString).utf8String, -1, nil)
            sqlite3_bind_text(insertStatement, 6, (theme as NSString).utf8String, -1, nil)
            sqlite3_bind_text(insertStatement, 7, (font as NSString).utf8String, -1, nil)
            sqlite3_bind_text(insertStatement, 8, (folderId as NSString).utf8String, -1, nil)
            sqlite3_bind_int(insertStatement, 9, Int32(isBookmarkedInt))
            
            if sqlite3_step(insertStatement) == SQLITE_DONE {
                //print("Successfully inserted row.")
            } else {
                //print("Could not insert row.")
            }
        } else {
            //print("INSERT statement could not be prepared.")
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(insertStatement)
    }
    
}
```

This is the error I am getting

```
2023-05-02 18:36:51.014049+0530 IQNote[5059:149954] [logging-persist] cannot open file at line 46922 of [554764a6e7]
2023-05-02 18:36:51.014160+0530 IQNote[5059:149954] [logging-persist] os_unix.c:46922: (0) open(/Users/nitish/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B08CC4B2-EE5E-41A9-A587-F265C33C209E/data/Containers/Data/Application/4FFBD6B1-CFA7-400E-95FD-9F7076AB280F/Documents/myDb.sqlite) - Undefined error: 0
2023-05-02 18:36:51.014510+0530 IQNote[5059:149954] [logging] API call with NULL database connection pointer
2023-05-02 18:36:51.014563+0530 IQNote[5059:149954] [logging] misuse at line 143209 of [554764a6e7]
2023-05-02 18:36:51.014603+0530 IQNote[5059:149954] [logging] API call with NULL database connection pointer
2023-05-02 18:36:51.014637+0530 IQNote[5059:149954] [logging] misuse at line 143209 of [554764a6e7]
2023-05-02 18:36:51.014674+0530 IQNote[5059:149954] [logging] API call with NULL database connection pointer
2023-05-02 18:36:51.014721+0530 IQNote[5059:149954] [logging] misuse at line 143209 of [554764a6e7]
```

I even tried to call openDatabase() only once when the app is launched (as you can see in the commented line). But that also didn't work. It gave the same error while making insert/read calls. Any help would be appreciated.

Tried to save & read data in sqlite db but getting intermittent error: "unable to open database file"

Comment: If this is so easy to reproduce have you tried to debug it? Or use print statements to follow what happens? I don't think there is enough info here for anyone else to reproduce your issue or identify the bug.

Comment: Not directly related to your issue but why do you have a db file in your app Bundle that you copy the first time as needed, but you attempt to create a new table? If you are going to have an initial db file that you can copy, why not include the table in that initial file? Then you don't need code to try to create the table every time the app runs.

Comment: @HangarRash I tried including table in the initial file as well. But there also after a few transactions it started showing the same error. Anyways, I removed the copy from bundle code to make it cleaner

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, I tried to debug and the thing is openDatabase() returns nil after some transactions and error message in my print statement shows `error opening database = unable to open database file`. Let me know what else should I print as I am little new to this

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found out what was going wrong. It was happening probably because I was opening multiple db connections without closing them. I added `sqlite3_close(db)` after each process and it solved the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).